# Openweathermap don't work for some countries?

Tags: openweathermap

I'm using json API data from openweathermap to get info about specific city.

It was working fine few days ago, and now for some reason every city marked with country code "RS" which is for Serbia, can't work.
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Belgrade,rs&APPID=MYAPI&units=metric&lang=hr

If I'm using cities in other countries, for example this, it's working:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Zagreb,hr&APPID=MYAPI&units=metric&lang=hr

Not really sure what's the difference here, and why "RS" country code isn't working?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug in their API, I got response from their support that they're working on it.